# Oracle not auto-generating primary key on insert

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key

New to Oracle here. I have a table created with the following SQL:

```
create table Widgets (
    id              integer constraint pkWidgets primary key using index,
    ruleId          integer not null,
    customerId      integer constraint fkWidgets_Customers references Customers
);
```

I'm now trying to insert a record into this table with:

```
INSERT INTO Widgets (
  ruleId,
  customerId
) VALUES (
  88471239,
  null
);
```

And getting the following error:

```
INSERT INTO Widgets not successful
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
INSERT INTO Widgets (
  ruleId,
  customerId...

ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("MYSCHEMA"."WIDGETS"."ID") [SQL State=23000, DB Errorcode=1400]
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 0.13s
```

**What's going on here?** Shouldn't Oracle be auto-generating my primary key (`id` field) value? If not, how can I tell (*exact SQL*) what needs to be inserted for this value?

Comment: Seems like you need to insert the id value as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use `ids.nextval` and my insert works great:

```
INSERT INTO Widgets (
  id,
  ruleId,
  customerId
) VALUES (
  ids.nextval,
  88471239,
  null
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Merely declaring something as a primary key does not cause the value to be generated.  In Oracle 12C, you can use:

```
id  integer generated always as identity primary key
```

In earlier versions, you would do this using a trigger.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff (+1), but I cannot change the way the table is created. Sounds like I need to provide my own ID on insert then?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup . . . Yes, a sequence would often be used for that.  Can you add a trigger?  Or alter the table?

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, I was told I could use `ids.nextval` as a solution and it works